# Android ClassNotFoundException error at runtime

Tags: java, android

I am developing an app in Android Studio. The package name is com.mycompany.myapp .  Then, I want to reuse some codes from another package : com.theta360.sample.v2 .

To do this, I added a package named "com.theta360.sample.v2" in Android studio. And then, I simply copied the src directory of com.theta360.sample.v2 to project/app/src/main/, which also includes mycompany/myapp .

In MainActivity.java.  I need to use class LogView from theta360.sample.v2.  So, added "import com.theta360.sample.v2.view.LogView".

Then, I successfully build the app.

However, when I launched the app on device, I received error with message:

..Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.view.LogView" on path: DexPathList...

My questions are:

(1) why at run-time, the system try to look for android.view.LogView; LogView is from com.theta360.sample.v2.view  . How to fix it?

(2) What's the correct way to use another package with source. Can I simply copy the codes as I did above?

Comment: You should'nt just copy src folder. You should import the project and run it. Copy only the code relevant to you. Always check package name , imported classes whilecopying

Comment: Have you tried Cleaning and Rebuilding the Project?

Comment: tried cleaning and rebuilding. same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my own question. The error is caused by LogView used in the layout xml. It should be changed to a name with it's package prefix.